# keep trying function until required DOM element is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading another page into an `el` via `XHR`. The loaded page has js on it that throws an error and fails unless the required dom element is loaded on the page. As it's XHR `.ready` et. al. won't work.

I have it working with a 500 ms timeout, but that's not OK; there has to be a better way. With timeout, the dom el doesn't always load and the page fails.

There is a table hard-coded on the page with an `id`. The script in the page is a jquery plugin (datatables) and won't init unless the table is loaded.

I've thought about having a function that inits the datatables stuff and calling that repeatedly `while` `$('#tableID')` is `null` but not sure that's correct.

```
<div id="contactQueue">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="contactsQueueTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 185px; ">Contact Name</th>
            <th class="" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 148px; ">Bus. Name</th>
            <th class="" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 116px; ">Is Client</th>
            <th class="" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 165px; ">Remove</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<?php echo form_open('',array('id'=>'step2form','name'=>'step2form'));?>
<input type="hidden" name="clientID" value="<?php echo $clientID; ?>">
<?php echo form_close();?>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
console.log(jq('#currentContactsTable'))
while(jq('#currentContactsTable').html()==null){
    initXHRPage();
    console.log(jq('#currentContactsTable')+' not ready');
}
function initXHRPage(){
    //init tables stuffs
}
```

---

EDIT;

The issue was something else, kinda. The script for Datatables is being loaded via `getScript()`. The element was being loaded normally, but `initDatatables()` was firing before *`getScript()`* was done loading, not before the el was loaded.

The solution was to call the `initDatatables()` function in the `getScript()` success callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var jsf = '/js/jquery.dataTables.js';
jq.getScript(jsf, function(data, textStatus){
    console.log('Loaded:'+jsf+" From: <?php echo $this->uri->uri_string(); ?>");
    initDatatable();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with. Thx to respondents for help.

```
initPage();

function initPage(){
    if(jq('#currentContactsTable').length==1){
            initDatatable();
    }else{
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                    initPage();
            },250);
    }
}

function initDatatable(){
    jq('#currentContactsTable').dataTable( {
            //REST OF DATATABLE STUFF...
```

It may not be super pretty as it still is relying on a timeout, but at least this timeout it a bit more robust...

---

^^^^ BZZZZZZZZZ

The issue was something else, kinda. The script for Datatables is being loaded via getScript(). The element was being loaded normally, but initDatatables() was firing before getScript() was done loading, not before the el was loaded.

The solution was to call the initDatatables() function in the getScript() success callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var jsf = '/js/jquery.dataTables.js';
jq.getScript(jsf, function(data, textStatus){
    console.log('Loaded:'+jsf+" From: <?php echo $this->uri->uri_string(); ?>");
    initDatatable();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `$(el).ready(...)`? That certainly ought to work. If it isn't, something else is going wrong.

---

**Edit**

Sorry, that should have been `$("#your_xhr_loaded_content").ready()...`.

I do this type of thing all the time and it works, I think the key is that I *am* loading a document.

*Main HTML document, index.html:*

```
    ...
    <body>
        ...
        <div id="activity_content">
        </div>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*main.js:*

```
...

function ruleManagement.loadContent() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "subdocs/ruleMgmt.html",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#activity_content").html(html);
            }
    }
}

ruleManagement.onReady = function(event) {
    // Init contents of the rule_management_pane
    ...
}
```

*HTML Sub-Document, ruleMgmt.html*

```
<div id="rule_management_pane">
    <!-- Content here -->
    ...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    jQuery("#rule_management_pane").ready(ruleManagement.onReady);
</script>
```

If I invoke `ruleManagement.loadContent()`, then `ruleManagement.onReady()` is called after div#rule_management_pane has been successfully loaded. I cannot say for sure that onReady is invoked before div#rule_management_pane is inserted into #activity_content, but I think that is the case.

Comment: The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) states `.ready()` can only be used on the document: _The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted._ So is `$(el).ready(...)` valid?

Comment: Doesn't work though. The page loads, that el isn't ready so the ready(function(){//blah doesn't go. if I replace el.ready with setTimeout 500, it works.

Comment: For some reason, it still doesn't work. I don't think it's so much an issue with XHR; the page is loaded via XHR, but the Datatables stuff isn't; it's a method called on an el that creates a table. There is XHR in DTBLS, but that's not the issue either. The problem is the page is loaded, the script on the page (that init's datatables) runs before the elements on said page are rendered/created and it balks because the el isn't there. doing `jq('#currentContactsTable').ready(function(){initDatatables();})` doesn't work: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dataTable'` thx

Answer (score 1):

how I understand your html/js is getting loaded:

- containerPage --> $.get(/ajax/getMiddlePage.php)
- middle XHR page --> $.get(/ajax/getContactQueue.php)
- middle XHR page --> $.get(/ajax/getCurrentContactsTable.php)

rough.  ok, here is what i think you need:

```
<html>
<!---CONTAINER PAGE--->
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //this .ready is to register events we need to catch the '#currentContactsTable' load event
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //ajaxSuccess is a global ajax function, you need to check ajaxOptions object to ensure you have the correct 'ajaxSuccess' you thought you did.
      $.ajaxSuccess(function(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions){
        if (ajaxOptions.url == '/ajax/getCurrentContactsTable.php') {
          $('#currentContactsTable').trigger('initDataTables');
        }
      });
// .live() does not need the element to exist on document.ready()
      $('#currentContactsTable').live('initDataTables', function(event){
          var dataTables = $(this).datatables({options:here});
      });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: i'm away from a development environment to give this a run, however, a combination of .live() and the 'ajaxSuccess' or 'ajaxComplete' jquery global ajax event is the path I would go down for a solution

Comment: Maybe I'm just dense, but how would this solve the problem? Page itself is loaded from an XHR request and I've tried doing the datatable init on it's onComplete callback with the same problem. Your solution is verifying the XHR success of the call to the datatable page, right? Thx.

Comment: this javascript goes in the 'container page'.  the XHR gets loaded into some 'container page'.  Even If the entire 'container page' receiving the new content is being completely re-written, the document.ready() still holds for the original DOM.

Comment: Rough indeed. It's a desktop-like app (mochaUI) so there are lots of XHR's. This page is Desktop->XHR->Page2->XHR->ContactsPage; it's like INCEPTION, but with a better plot. As you said, `live()` doesn't need the el to exist, but Datatables does. That's really where the issue was--datatables would init before its div was created and balk because the div didn't exist. I think ready isn't working precisely because, as you said, the OG `.ready()` for the doc (index.php or whatever) is true and any doc.ready's on any XHR pages see `.ready()==true` from index.php and don't fire. Thx for the reply.